# Refactor form to partial

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have two registration forms, both for `Customer` model but with different fields.

#### Form 1

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer, url: registration_path do |f| %>
...
   <%= f.input_field :marketing, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, id: "marketing" %>
<% end %>
```

#### Form 2

...

Form 1 has consent checkboxes which need to be checked. I want to add same the consent checkboxes to the other form. I moved the checkboxes part to a partial and render it in the form but I get an error:

`udnefined variable or method 'f'`

#### partial `shared/_consents.html.erb`

```
<%= f.input_field :marketing, as: :boolean, boolean_style: :inline, id: "marketing" %>
```

How can I refactor the original form so I can have a separate partial which I could add to the other form?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the form builder object (`f` variable) to the partial, e.g.

```
render partial: 'shared/consents.html.erb', locals: {f: f}
```

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/layouts_and_rendering.html#passing-local-variables